# csv writerows only writing the first row but not others

Tags: python, csv, writer

i am trying to write some data into a new csv i am trying to split the text by percentage but fails to do so, when i write into csv it only writes the col names of the old csv into the new one all other lines are not there.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in dirs:
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path+"/"+directory+"/"):
            for file in files:
                if file != "Bomgar.csv":


  text=pd.read_csv("/Users/vkhar12/sentinail_data_scrubing/"+directory+"/"+file)
                    line_count = math.ceil((text.shape[0] * 20) / 100)
                    start=text[:line_count]
            with open("start.csv","w") as myfile:
                wr=csv.writer(myfile)
                wr.writerows([start])
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly you are trying to write?

Comment: my parent csv has 2 col and each col has 22 rows but it only writes the header for both col in to the new csv

Comment: Ok, so your idea is to move the content from one dataframe to another?

Comment: yes that is right

Answer (score 0):

Since your idea is to just move the content from one .csv to another, I highly suggest using the pandas library and creating a dataframe to do so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(old_file_path, sep = ',')
df = df.drop(list_of_columns_to_delete, axis=1)
df.to_csv(new_file_path, ',')
```

If you don't have pandas, pip install it with `pip install pandas`.

Comment: but i do not have to move all the content to new csv

Comment: What do you want to move? I removed some columns, for example

Comment: i want to add lines from old csv based on the formula i used to calulate the percentage for eg. if my old csv has two col and has 22 lines in both the col i want to add 20% of the old csv means 20% of lines starting from beggning of file into new  csv

Comment: Sorry, without seeing more of your code it's hard to help much more. However, I suggest you execute your calculations in a pandas dataframe version of your original CSV (for example, executing the calculations in the ```df``` variable in the above example). If there's anything else I can help you with, just let me know ;)